# Having trouble using CUDA enabled OpenCV with kinetic

Tags: ros, opencv, ros-kinetic, libopencv, cuda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.

I started a new install of ROS Kinetic, and I was hoping to use a few CUDA features from OpenCV. I have successfully compiled and tested CUDA and OpenCV (which is installed in /usr/local), but I am having trouble using my OpenCV instead of the `ros-kinetic-opencv3` package.

I have tried adding /usr/local to the front of my CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, as well renaming the opencv pkgconfig file in /opt/ros/lib/pkconfig. However I still get the below error, indicating that I am building against the ROS OpenCv.

```
OpenCV Error: No CUDA support (The library is compiled without CUDA support) in throw_no_cuda, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.1.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp, line 97
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.1.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp:97: error: (-216) The library is compiled without CUDA support in function throw_no_cuda
```

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242376/having-trouble-using-cuda-enabled-opencv-with-kinetic/) by [daniel_dsouza](https://answers.ros.org/users/22498/daniel_dsouza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2016-08-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-25**:
It looks like its loading the wrong library at runtime; this is usually controlled by the system library search paths (ldconfig) and LD_LIBRARY_PATH

**Comment by [daniel_dsouza](https://answers.ros.org/users/22498/daniel_dsouza/) on 2016-08-25**:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH looks like /usr/local/lib:/home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib

shouldn't it be pulling from /usr/local/lib where OpenCV is first if that was the case?

**Comment by [daniel_dsouza](https://answers.ros.org/users/22498/daniel_dsouza/) on 2016-08-25**:
if I manually run the CMakeLists.txt file, then the code build and executes correctly. However using catkin_make give different results?

**Comment by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on 2017-06-15**:
@daniel_dsouza, how did you run it manually? Just CMake .. and make?

**Comment by [daniel_dsouza](https://answers.ros.org/users/22498/daniel_dsouza/) on 2017-06-15**:
I believe so. Do you have a Github link to your code? I can try to compile it myself.

**Comment by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on 2017-06-15**:
https://github.com/ashnarayan13/stereo_works.git this is the code.

**Comment by [daniel_dsouza](https://answers.ros.org/users/22498/daniel_dsouza/) on 2017-06-15**:
Could you please link your entire ros package? Until then, look at this (working) example https://github.com/daniel-dsouza/solid-succotash

**Comment by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on 2017-06-15**:
@daniel_dsouza I have added the entire projecct on git. I will look into your project as well! Thanks!

**Comment by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on 2017-06-19**:
my CMakeCache.txt points the opencv dir to /usr/local/share/OpenCV but the headers i require are in /usr/local/include/opencv2 . Even if set the cmake cache to that location, i get an error and then resets to share/opencv.
I get undefined reference to `cv::cuda::createStereoBM(int, int)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello previous me,

So you have the opencv3 package installed, which provides libraries in `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib,` and you also have OpenCV compiled from source, installed to `usr/local`. The trick is to tell catkin to use the libraries from `usr/local`.

By default, catkin is hardwired to look for packages in your workspace, then in `/opt/ros/kinetic`. CMake by itself will use the libraries in `/usr/local`. I tried to prioritize `/usr/local` by modifying the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` environment variable, as suggested in pre kinetic posts, but no luck.

So if I cannot modify catkin itself, I should to explicitly tell CMake which OpenCV to use. I had to change my declaration from

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
```

to

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED
NO_MODULE # should be optional, tells CMake to use config mode
PATHS /usr/local # look here
NO_DEFAULT_PATH) # and don't look anywhere else
```

So that will pull in the correct libraries. If another package is built that requires OpenCV, catkin will also pull in the wrong dependencies. Mixed dependencies is a bad thing. So you have to add the modified OpenCV configuration to any other packages that require OpenCV. This includes the `vision_opencv` package that provides `cv_bridge`.

UPDATE 10/12/2017:
Please see my [fork of vision_opencv](https://github.com/daniel-dsouza/vision_opencv) for the necessary changes and my cvTest example package. In the example, I demonstrate the use of my custom version of OpenCV 3.3 build with CUDA 8.

---

Originally posted by [daniel_dsouza](https://answers.ros.org/users/22498/daniel_dsouza/) with karma: 258 on 2016-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on 2017-05-27**:
I have a similar problem. I replaced the CMake file as you have, but I still get the same error.
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED
NO_MODULE
PATHS /usr/local
NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
I can compile the code and run it outside ROS.

**Comment by [naveenT1010](https://answers.ros.org/users/30447/naveent1010/) on 2017-05-28**:
ashwath1993 did you recompile other packages dependent on opencv or not? I was also having a similar problem, but when I compiled the vision_opencv from source, it all worked.

**Comment by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on 2017-06-12**:
I am able to run the opencv samples from the same path. Doesn't work with ROS alone.

**Comment by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on 2017-06-15**:
what():  /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.2.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp:97: error: (-216) The library is compiled without CUDA support in function throw_no_cuda
My CMakeLists.txt contain the same find_package as you have mentioned

**Comment by [k_totoro](https://answers.ros.org/users/32221/k_totoro/) on 2017-10-12**:
Hi. I have same trouble and got same error.
In the sentence "So you have to add the modified OpenCV configuration to any other packages that require OpenCV.", do you mean I have to change all Cmakelist in my packages?

**Comment by [daniel_dsouza](https://answers.ros.org/users/22498/daniel_dsouza/) on 2017-10-12**:
@k_totoro Hello. I had to download the [vision_opencv metapackage](http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv) , and make the above changes to the cv_bridge and image_geometry packages' CMakeLists.txt. You only need to make the changes in packages that use/are used by your node that uses your custom OpenCV.

**Comment by [daniel_dsouza](https://answers.ros.org/users/22498/daniel_dsouza/) on 2017-10-12**:
@k_totoro, please see the update to my answer with the github repo

**Comment by [k_totoro](https://answers.ros.org/users/32221/k_totoro/) on 2017-10-13**:
Thank you daniel. I read your Github sample but still do not understand what you mean.
So, I have to remove my "cv_bridge" or some package from apt-get and rebuild it for myself?
Your test CMake file in CVTest looks the same with mine.

**Comment by [k_totoro](https://answers.ros.org/users/32221/k_totoro/) on 2017-10-13**:
Finally, I found I had to exclude opencvcore3.so in my catkin_libraries.
Here is my issue and thank you for your help!
https://answers.ros.org/question/272814/how-to-tell-catkin_make-to-use-opencv-with-gpu/
My sample project:
https://github.com/YoshiRi/ros_opencv_conflict/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

**Comment by [daniel_dsouza](https://answers.ros.org/users/22498/daniel_dsouza/) on 2017-10-14**:
Good for you! To answer your question, you would have to recompile the packages in vision_opencv to make sure the correct libs are used. You could use the fork I posted.

**Comment by [surfertas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27828/surfertas/) on 2017-10-26**:
@daniel_dsouza @k_totoro
In my case, I took the following steps after all the steps mentioned above.

```
$ cd catkin_ws/src
$ git clone https://github.com/daniel-dsouza/vision_opencv.git
$ cd ..
$ catkin clean
$ catkin build
```

Which seemed to do the job. I didnt have to remove any additional file

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-10-11**:
@daniel_dsouza thank you so much, I just downloaded your  https://github.com/daniel-dsouza/vision_opencv  in my **~/catkin_ws/src/**, then making **~/catkin_ws/**`catkin_make` on my PC, It is very nice but tried to use the same steps in my Jetson TX2 with OpenCV4Tegra because I don't need to build OpenCV like on my PC but get this **ERROR** , you can see [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/335157/invoking-make-cmake_check_build_system-failed/)   in  my question. I think that the issue in the path, please help me or any suggestions?

**Comment by [j.clownz](https://answers.ros.org/users/45405/j.clownz/) on 2021-02-17**:
@daniel_dsouza That saved my life. Thanks man!